# RoR: Problems with prefilled forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm new to RoR and have a little question.

I have a table like

```
<td>Some Informations</td>
<td><a href="">Register me</a></td>
```

If the user clicks on one of these links, he will forwarded to a new form where he can add some informations... These form ist prefilled with some placeholder-data like

```
<input tye="input" placeholder"<%= @spot.reference %>">
```

When all required informations has been filled out, everythings works - but if the user forgets a field, he should return to the form with some error informations.

Well, i have some other forms where everything works fine, but in this case, my prefilled fields making some problems..

```
undefined method `reference' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #15):
<input type="hidden" name="trip[reference]" value="<%= @spot.reference %>">
```

What should i do to ensure that the fields are prefilled again?
This is my code...

```
class TripsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
  end

  # show the givin trip
  def show
    @trip = Trip.find(params[:id])
  end

  # show the new template
  # the user can configurate his trip
  def new
    @trip = Trip.new
    connect_google
  end

  def all
    @trips = Trip.all
  end

  # create a new trip and set the current user as trip-admin
  def create
    @trip = Trip.new(trip_params.merge(admin: current_user.id))
    @trip.admin = current_user.id
    if @trip.save
      attach(@trip)
      redirect_to @trip
    else
      connect_google
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def attach(trip)
    current_user.attend(trip)
  end

  private
    def trip_params
      params.require(:trip).permit(:reference, :hotel, :from, :to, :notice)
    end

    def connect_google
      @googlePlaces = GooglePlaces::Client.new('API KEY')
      @spot = @googlePlaces.spot(params[:id])
      rescue GooglePlaces::InvalidRequestError
        #redirect_to '/' and return
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have not defined `@spot` variable in your controller for which you are asking for it's reference field. Define `@spot` in your `show` or `new` function in your controller depending on which page your form exists and it should work.

Comment: I define @spot in my private method "connect_google". This works for my "new" method but not for my "create" and i dont know why...

Comment: That maybe because when the create function is called, the parameter `:id` does not go with it at the route changes. try storing the last used `:id` and using that id.